# How do I make this serial config code configurable?

Tags: c++, serial-port

in my serial com class
`options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD | CS8);`

I want to make `|= ( CLOCAL | CREAD | CS8)` editable, as in I will read in this portion from a text file and "append" to the `options.c_cflag`.

I tried using a `string` variable but can't make it work.
Anyone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code to achieve this, because basically you're trying to compile C code at runtime.

You can use regular expression engines or simple string splitting to extract each component, then convert them from string to symbol (with a table or something like : if(!strcmp(text,"CLOCAL")) v=CLOCAL; ).

Answer (score 0):

OR'd flags gives you an actual numeric value, which can be read and converted to that value by `stringstream`.

```
template<typename T>
T flagValue(const std::string& flag_str)
{
    T value;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << hex << flag_str;
    ss >> value;
    return value;
}
```

But You need to know exact value of OR'd flags, write it somewhere and assign `options.c_flag` with the result of flagValue.

For example `flagValue<unsigned int>("1a")`.